# Is Pushkin Пу́шкин or Пушкин ? Does the у́ matter?

Tags: пунктуация

When I type Pushkin into google translate, it returns "Пушкин". On the other hand, when I look at [english wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Pushkin), it says "Пу́шкин". [Russian wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) also has "Пу́шкин".

Which should be used in an English publication? Should the APA-LC be Pushkin or  Pу́shkin?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That dash above the **у́** is called "stress accent". Wikipedia marks stress accent in the names of its articles. Such stress accents are not written in most of the Russian texts, they are used mostly in encyclopedias, dictionaries, Russian textbooks ans sometimes in books for children. The stress on **y** means that it is this vowel sound which is the loudest and longest in the word, in Russian you pronounce *Пушкин* as POOSH-kin. Again, in usual texts those stress accents are *not* used. Note that later in the Russian Wikipedia article no stress accent is put. In English the standart spelling of that surname is `Pushkin`.

Comment: Only cases where they are used in text is when it meant to distinguish meaning of homomorphic words, e.g. чудно́ vs чудно (stress on first sillabe), to prevent improper stress in  well-known  words with  unusual stress, or to emphasize differences, e.g. between union что and pronoun что.